# Elasticsearch : search results on clicking on Hashtag

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, camelcasing

I have a hashtag with tags in camel Case like #teamIndia. Now when this hashtag is clicked, it should fetch all results which have "#teamIndia" in it, It should first show results with "#teamIndia", then results with "teamIndia" and then "team India" and then "team" or "India" and so on.

What I am doing:

Search text:
**"#teamIndia", "#NEWYORK", "#profession", "#2016"**

```
POST /clip
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter" : {
                "space_hashtags" : {
                    "type" : "mapping",
                    "mappings" : ["#=>|#"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "substring": {
                    "max_gram": "20",
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": "1",
                    "token_chars": [
                        "whitespace"
                    ]
                },
                "camelcase": {
                    "type": "word_delimiter",
                    "type_table": ["# => ALPHANUM", "@ => ALPHANUM"]
                },
                "stopword": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords": ["and", "is", "the"]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "substring_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "substring"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                },
                "camelcase_analyzer": {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "char_filter" : "space_hashtags",
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "camelcase",
                        "lowercase",
                        "stopword"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "Clip": {
            "properties": {
                "description": {
                    "type": "multi_field",
                    "fields": {
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "substring_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "hashtag": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "analyzed",
                            "analyzer": "camelcase_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                },
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Docs example :-

```
POST /clip/Clip/2 {"id" : 1, "description" : "TheBestAndTheBeast"}

POST /clip/Clip/3 {"id" : 2, "description" : "bikes in DUBAI TheBestAndTheBeast profession"}

POST /clip/Clip/3 {"id" : 2, "description" : "Know how a software engineer surprised his wife!    &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23theProvider&amp;source=hashtag&quot; ng-click=&quot;handleModalClick()&quot;&gt; #theProvider &lt;/a&gt;     rioOlympic   &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23DUBAI&amp;source=hashtag&quot; ng-click=&quot;handleModalClick()&quot;&gt; #DUBAI &lt;/a&gt;    &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23TheBestAndTheBeast&amp;source=hashtag&quot; ng-click=&quot;handleModalClick()&quot;&gt; #TheBestAndTheBeast &lt;/a&gt;   &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23rioOlympic&amp;source=hashtag&quot; ng-click=&quot;handleModalClick()&quot;&gt; #rioOlympic &lt;/a&gt;"}
```

** Search Query **

```
GET clip/_search
{
"size": 100,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must":
                   {
                    "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                           "description.hashtag"
                        ],
                        "query": "teamIndia"
                    }                         
                },
                "should": { 
                    "match": 
                        { "description.raw": "#teamIndia"}   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Excepted Result:**
"#teamIndia",
"teamIndia",
"team India",
"team",
"India",

and similar for other test keywords.

Comment: Can you also provide a few sample docs?

Comment: Do you mean sample resultset? @Val

Comment: Some sample docs just so people can easily recreate your environment and test their solutions.

Comment: I have updated the question adding 2 sample doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons the query in the original post does not work as intended is because `description.raw` is `not_analyzed` . 
As a result `#teamIndia` would never match a document with `description: "Animals and Pets and #teamIndia"` since the `description.raw` would contain 
the non-analyzed term `Animals and Pets and #teamIndia` and not `#teamIndia`

Assuming that the documents you have are like 2nd example in the OP.

**Example:**

```
{"id" : 2, "description" : "Animals and Pets and #teamIndia"}
```

OR

```
{"id":7,"description":"This &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23teamIndia&amp;source=hashtag&quot;&gt;#teamIndia&lt;/a&gt;"}
```

Then you should be able to rank documents in the following order :

1) description containing "#teamIndia",
2) description containing  "teamIndia"
3) description containing "team India"
4) description containing "India"

by enabling `preserve_orginal` and `catenate_words` in the [wordlimiter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) filter as shown in the example below

**Example:**

**Index Documents**

```
 PUT clip
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "char_filter": {
            "zwsp_normalize": {
               "type": "mapping",
               "mappings": [
                  "\\u200B=>",
                  "\\u200C=>",
                  "\\u200D=>"
               ]
            },
            "html_decoder": {
               "type": "mapping",
               "mappings": [
                  "&lt;=> <",
                  "&gt;=> >"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "camelcase": {
               "type": "word_delimiter",
               "preserve_original": "true",
               "catenate_all": "true"
            },
            "stopword": {
               "type": "stop",
               "stopwords": [
                  "and",
                  "is",
                  "the"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "camelcase_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "camelcase",
                  "lowercase",
                  "stopword"
               ],
               "char_filter": [
                  "zwsp_normalize",
                  "html_decoder",
                  "html_strip"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "Clip": {
         "properties": {
            "description": {
               "type": "multi_field",
               "fields": {
                  "hashtag": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "analyzed",
                     "analyzer": "camelcase_analyzer",
                     "norms": {
                         "enabled": false
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}



POST /clip/Clip/1
{
   "id": 1,
   "description": "Animals and Pets and #teamIndia"
}

POST /clip/Clip/2 
{
   "id": 2,
   "description": "Animals and Pets and teamIndia"
}


POST /clip/Clip/3
{
   "id": 3,
   "description": "Animals and Pets and team India"
}


POST /clip/Clip/4 
{
   "id": 4,
   "description": "Animals and Pets and India"
}



  POST /clip/Clip/7
    {
       "id": 7,
       "description": "This &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23teamIndia&amp;source=hashtag&quot;&gt;#teamIndia&lt;/a&gt;"
    }
```

**Query Result:**

```
POST clip/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                           "description.hashtag"
                        ],
                        "query": "#teamIndia"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Results:**

```
      "hits": {
      "total": 5,
      "max_score": 1.4969246,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "7",
            "_score": 1.4969246,
            "_source": {
               "id": 7,
               "description": "This &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23teamIndia&amp;source=hashtag&quot;&gt;#teamIndia&lt;/a&gt;"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.4969246,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "description": "Animals and Pets and #teamIndia"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0952718,
            "_source": {
               "id": 2,
               "description": "Animals and Pets and teamIndia"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.5207714,
            "_source": {
               "id": 3,
               "description": "Animals and Pets and team India"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.11123338,
            "_source": {
               "id": 4,
               "description": "Animals and Pets and India"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

Example #dubai:

```
POST /clip/Clip/5
{
   "id": 5,
   "description": "#dubai is hot"
}

POST /clip/Clip/6
{
   "id": 6,
   "description": "dubai airport is huge"
}

POST clip/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                           "description.hashtag"
                        ],
                        "query": "#dubai"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1.820827,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": 1.820827,
            "_source": {
               "id": 5,
               "description": "#dubai is hot"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "6",
            "_score": 0.5856731,
            "_source": {
               "id": 6,
               "description": "dubai airport is huge"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

Example #professionalAndPunctual :

```
POST /clip/Clip/7
{
   "id": 7,
   "description": "professionalAndPunctual"
}
POST clip/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                           "description.hashtag"
                        ],
                        "query": "#professionalAndPunctual"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
} 

 "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "clip",
        "_type": "Clip",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 2.2149992,
        "_source": {
           "id": 7,
           "description": "professionalAndPunctual"
        }
     }
  ]
```

### **Edited Example**

**Example: #TheBestAndTheBea‌​st**

```
   POST /clip/Clip/10
{"id" : 10, "description" : "TheBestAndTheBeast"}

POST /clip/Clip/11
{"id" :11, "description" : "bikes in DUBAI TheBestAndTheBeast profession"}

POST /clip/Clip/12
{"id" : 12, "description" : "Know how a software engineer surprised his wife! <a href=\"search/clips?q=%23theProvider&source=hashtag\" ng-click=\"handleModalClick()\"> #theProvider </a> rioOlympic <a href=\"search/clips?q=%23DUBAI&source=hashtag\" ng-click=\"handleModalClick()\"> #DUBAI </a> <a href=\"search/clips?q=%23TheBestAndTheBeast&source=hashtag\" ng-click=\"handleModalClick()\"> #TheBestAndTheBeast </a> <a href=\"search/clips?q=%23rioOlympic&source=hashtag\" ng-click=\"handleModalClick()\"> #rioOlympic </a>"}

POST clip/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                           "description.hashtag"
                        ],
                        "query": "#TheBestAndTheBeast"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

#Results

```
 "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "12",
            "_score": 1.8701664,
            "_source": {
               "id": 12,
               "description": "Know how a software engineer surprised his wife! <a href=\"search/clips?q=%23theProvider&source=hashtag\" ng-click=\"handleModalClick()\"> #theProvider </a> rioOlympic <a href=\"search/clips?q=%23DUBAI&source=hashtag\" ng-click=\"handleModalClick()\"> #DUBAI </a> <a href=\"search/clips?q=%23TheBestAndTheBeast&source=hashtag\" ng-click=\"handleModalClick()\"> #TheBestAndTheBeast </a> <a href=\"search/clips?q=%23rioOlympic&source=hashtag\" ng-click=\"handleModalClick()\"> #rioOlympic </a>"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "10",
            "_score": 0.9263139,
            "_source": {
               "id": 10,
               "description": "TheBestAndTheBeast"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "clip",
            "_type": "Clip",
            "_id": "11",
            "_score": 0.9263139,
            "_source": {
               "id": 11,
               "description": "bikes in DUBAI TheBestAndTheBeast profession"
            }
         }
      ]
```

**Analyzer Example** :

```
get clip/_analyze?analyzer=camelcase_analyzer&text=%23DUBAI

   {
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "#dubai",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "dubai",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 0
      }
   ]
}

get clip/_analyze?analyzer=camelcase_analyzer&text=This%20%26lt%3Ba%20href%3D%26quot%3Bsearch%2Fclips%3Fq%3D%2523teamIndia%26amp%3Bsource%3Dhashtag%26quot%3B%26gt%3B%23teamIndia%26lt%3B%2Fa%26gt%3B

  {
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "this",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "#teamindia",
         "start_offset": 78,
         "end_offset": 98,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "india",
         "start_offset": 78,
         "end_offset": 98,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "team",
         "start_offset": 78,
         "end_offset": 98,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "teamindia",
         "start_offset": 78,
         "end_offset": 98,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the single word like #profession or #DUBAI. When these elements are searched the result set doesn't consist of words only like profession or dubai i.e. words without hashtag. and also if hashtag like #professionalAndPunctual is searched search result doesn't have results with only professional (without hashtag) keyword in it

Comment: weird works for me , have added the updated examples to the answer above ? are you sure the description data format and analyzer are as shown in the example above ?

Comment: the first document format is way different from the 2nd . The kind of analyzer you should use here would be very different ? Could you repost  in the question the all the varipus f format the document description could be . Would be easier to design an analyzer.

Comment: If I have data like "bikes in DUBAI TheBestAndTheBeast profession" or "#DUBAI" or "I like DUBAI" and when searched for "#DUBAI", the result does not include data as "I like DUBAI" and  "bikes in DUBAI TheBestAndTheBeast profession"

Comment: I have reposted the question and the description format will be like this for most of the cases 
  "description" : "This &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23teamIndia&amp;source=hashtag&quot;&gt;#teamIndia&lt;/a&gt;"

Comment: cool thanks just one more question for the format `"This &lt;a href=&quot;search/clips?q=%23teamIndia&amp;source=hashtag&qu‌​ot;&gt;#teamIndia&lt‌​;/a&gt;" ` what are the desirable tokens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125189/discussion-between-keety-and-kunal-dethe).

Comment: have updated the answer with the new analyzer .As specified this analyzer ignores the html-tags example:  `<a href="url"> `.

Comment: what exactly is not working i tried the example description with #TheBestAndTheBeast / #profession and i do get the desired results. See the updated example in the answer

Comment: Yes issue is still there. I have just edit the data set. It should list the data first based on hashtag occurs or not then it should list rest of the data

Comment: i see what you mean , i have updated the mapping in the answer. Essentially looks like for your use-case you would need to [disable norms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scoring-theory.html#field-norml)  else it would give  shorter fields  higher boosts.

Comment: did disabling norm not help as showing in the answer ?

Comment: Thanks @keety Now, after disabling norm, it is giving results in right order.

Comment: sure np ! when you get a chance could you accept the answer ! looks like i lost the bounty :)